# Villagers sometimes kill the wrong sheep

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-de

Context: During the Feudal start, I've lined up my sheep under my TC, and shift-clicked through them to kill and collect them in order.

Sometimes one or two of my villagers will ignore the command queue and just kill one of the *other* sheep instead (leading to lost food :( )

Why is that, and what should I do/avoid doing, to prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to gather from a resource, villagers need to go to a free spot next to the resource. If they can't find or reach a free spot, they'll look nearby for another resource of the same type and gather from there instead.

In the case of hunting, that means your villager will proceed to kill their next prey and gather from it.

This can happen for multiple reasons:

- The animal wandered too close to a building, a cliff, another resource (tree, deposit, etc.) or the edge of the map before it died. This reduces the number of open spots to gather from, since villagers can't move where there's an obstacle.
- There are too many villagers gathering from the animal, so there's no free spot left next to the carcass.
- While moving to gather, the villager's path was blocked (e.g. by another villager moving towards the animal) and couldn't find an alternative path to an open gathering spot.

Unfortunately, there's very little you can do to prevent this, other than careful micromanagement.

Comment: `While moving to gather, the villager's path was blocked (e.g. by another villager moving towards the animal) and couldn't find an alternative path to an open gathering spot.` If I've understood you correctly, then you're saying that if a villager ends up temporarily blocked in on all sides, whilst the group realigns to a new target, then it'll go idle and (roughly) lose its queued actions. Is that right?

Comment: @Brondahl, I'm not sure if the villager will lose the queue. My guess is it'll move to the next queued target: 1 > 2 (can't reach) > 3. but it's also possible that it'll select the next-best target instead as a replacement, then proceed with the queue: 1 > 2 (can't reach) > 4 (closest alternative target) > 3 > 4 (already dead) > 5.